# Framework not found Protobuf

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase-remote-config

[image]I am facing an issue wherein I needed to use FirebaseRemoteConfig for my iOS app. I included the following pod:

```
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
```

Now when I am running the command on terminal:

```
pod install
```

It shows me the error:

```
Framework not found 'Protobuf'
```

Its really frustrating as the project was running fine before this. I have tried some suggestions from stack overflow but could not resolve the issue.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

use_frameworks!
target 'S****k' do
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.2'
pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 1.1'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
pod 'Mantle', '~> 2.0'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'#, '~> 4.8'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'#, '~> 4.8'
pod 'GooglePlaces', '~> 3.0.0'
#pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'GoogleTagManager'
pod 'GoogleIDFASupport'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'AppsFlyerFramework'
pod 'KissXML'
pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 3.0.0'
pod 'AutoScrollLabel'
pod "CleverTap-iOS-SDK"
pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
pod 'TrueSDK'
pod 'HyperSDK', '0.2.90'
pod 'ExpressCheckout'
#pod "AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout"
pod 'UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout'
#pod 'TGLParallaxCarousel'
pod "JuspaySafeBrowser"
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
```

Comment: protobuf is something embed inside FirebaseCore. did you include it in your pod file? show us your podfile and more screenshot of the error.

Comment: I have edited the post.... This is how my pod file looks.

Comment: why you commented `pod Firebase/Core`? I think that's where you're missing `protobuf` framework

Comment: Even if I uncomment it, it doesn't work

Comment: How about clean build folder, delete `.xcworkspace`, `Pods/`, run `pod update` and try again? Also check your pod project (in project navigator) to see if `Protobuf` framework got installed correctly (Project navigators -> Targets)

Comment: Try to upgrade Protobuf to `v3.12.0` if you put your project code in case sensitive volume. Check this change: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/commit/56c48ae59267d27cee5cfacd732b8a706993fea0

Answer (score 4):

1. PLEASE BACKUP YOUR PROJECT
2. Let's go to  "Your Project" -> Build Settings
3. find here Find here "Other Linker Flags" and open it
4. delete (click on "-" sign) string "Protobuf" and string "framework" above "Protobuf"
5. clean build Folder (Command + SHIFT + K) and rebuild
6. that's all

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Project target
2. Go to build phases
3. Search Protobuf
4. delete Protobuf framework
5. Clean build folder and then build

It is worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me

```
delete pods
delete .symlinks
flutter clean
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this error by opening the xcworkspace file and then dragging my xcodeproj file into the left panel. After doing this I selected the project container folder and was able to build my project correctly. The pod installation didn't complete correctly and I needed to manually do this procedure.